# Xcode 4.4.1 CPU hog after simulation stopped

Tags: xcode, cpu-usage

Something seems to happen with my Xcode.

When running the project for the first time it goes good but when I stop the execution, 100% of CPU keeps being eaten by Xcode, if I try to run the project again the CPU escalates to eat almost 200% of the CPU then freezes Xcode.

If a kill Xcode then start it again the process repeats, only the first run goes well and when stopped the CPU gets hogged at 100%.

While searching for answers I noted that after waiting like 15 minutes or so with the memory hogged at 100% suddenly Xcode release it.

Tried restarting Xcode and computer with no luck.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems Xcode 4.5 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding like the "Repair Disk Permission" panacea, you may want to try deleting the DerivedData folder for your project. It's at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. There have been multiple reports (some from people I trust) that Xcode frequently gets confused due to corrupted data in that folder.

Comment: Sorry. That's the last time I suggest that!